# Creating a dictionary inside another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Given the following data how can I create a dictionary where the keys are the names of the students, and the values are dictionaries where the key is the test and it´s value is the grade they got in it.

```
grades =  [
   ['Students', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
   ['Tomas', '100', '90', '80'],
   ['Marcos', '88', '99', '111'],
   ['Flavia', '45', '56', '67'],
   ['Ramon', '59', '61', '67'],
   ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
   ['Federico', '89', '97', '101']
]
```

I tried doing this, but I don´t know why it´s not showing the grades correctly.

```
notas_dict={}

def dic(etiquets, notas):
   for i in range(len(etiquets)):
       notas_dict[etiquets[i]]=int(notas[i])
   return notas_dict
dic(['Test 1','Test 2', 'Test 3'], ['100','80','90'] )

dic_final={}

for line in grades[1:]:
   line_grades=[int(element) for element in line[1:]]
   dic_final[line[0]]=dic(['Test 1','Test 2', 'Test 3'], line_grades)
print(dic_final)
```

The output should be :

```
{'Tomas': {'Test 1': 100, 'Test 2': 90, 'Test 3': 80}, 'Marcos': {'Test 1': 88, 'Test 2': 99, 'Test 3': 111}, 'Flavia': {'Test 1': 45, 'Test 2': 56, 'Test 3': 67}, 'Ramon': {'Test 1': 59, 'Test 2': 61, 'Test 3': 67}, 'Ursula': {'Test 1': 73, 'Test 2': 79, 'Test 3': 83}, 'Federico': {'Test 1': 89, 'Test 2': 97, 'Test 3': 101}}
```

Comment: What's `dic`? You don't define it anywhere. Also, what output do you get?

Comment: dic was a function I created in order to create the dictionaries that will go as values (my bad I forgot to put the code but i edited it). And the output I got was:      
`{'Tomas': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}, 'Marcos': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}, 'Flavia': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}, 'Ramon': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}, 'Ursula': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}, 'Federico': {'Control 1': 89, 'Control 2': 97, 'Control 3': 101}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{i[0]:dict(zip(grades[0][1:],i[1:])) for i in grades[1:]}
```

results in:

```
{'Tomas': {'Test 1': '100', 'Test 2': '90', 'Test 3': '80'},
 'Marcos': {'Test 1': '88', 'Test 2': '99', 'Test 3': '111'},
 'Flavia': {'Test 1': '45', 'Test 2': '56', 'Test 3': '67'},
 'Ramon': {'Test 1': '59', 'Test 2': '61', 'Test 3': '67'},
 'Ursula': {'Test 1': '73', 'Test 2': '79', 'Test 3': '83'},
 'Federico': {'Test 1': '89', 'Test 2': '97', 'Test 3': '101'}}
```

If you want to get grades as int:

```
{i[0]:dict(zip(grades[0][1:],list(map(int,i[1:])))) for i in grades[1:]}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the grades as ints?

Comment: Updated! You can map int function to whole list: `{i[0]:dict(zip(grades[0][1:],list(map(int,i[1:])))) for i in grades[1:]}`

Answer (score 0):

create a dataframe then use to_records to create a list of tuples where each tuple is a row.  You can then slice the tuple by index.

```
 grades =  [
   ['Students', 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'],
   ['Tomas', '100', '90', '80'],
   ['Marcos', '88', '99', '111'],
   ['Flavia', '45', '56', '67'],
   ['Ramon', '59', '61', '67'],
  ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
  ['Federico', '89', '97', '101']
 ] 

 Columns=grades[0]
 df=pd.DataFrame(columns=Columns)
 for i in range(1, len(grades)):
     df_length = len(df)
     df.loc[df_length] = grades[i]

 print(df.to_records())
```

output:

```
 [(0, 'Tomas', '100', '90', '80') (1, 'Marcos', '88', '99', '111')
 (2, 'Flavia', '45', '56', '67') (3, 'Ramon', '59', '61', '67')
 (4, 'Ursula', '73', '79', '83') (5, 'Federico', '89', '97', '101')]
```

or

```
 dict=df.T.to_dict()
 for k,v in dict.items():
     print(k,v['Students'],v['Test1'],v['Test2'],v['Test3'])
```